# Is an array address random or fixed?

Tags: c, arrays

```
typedef int zip_dig[5];
zip_dig cmu = { 1, 5, 2, 1, 3 };
```

Let's say we run this program for the first time, and cmu's address is 20 in the stack. When we run this program again, is cmu's address still 20 in the stack, or a different number? If they are different addresses, what makes them different: the compiler or operating systems?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization

Comment: @liliscent Good answer! If you post it I will upvote it.

Answer (score 3):

Most modern operating systems supports some kind of ASLR (Address Space Layout Randomization) which is randomization of  the addresses of the stack, loading address and more. Google ASLR if you want more detailed answer.